# How to change font size and/or style in the vuetify data-table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have the following code, which renders the expected table:

```
<v-data-table
    dense
    :headers="table_headers"
    :items="table_data"
    :items-per-page="table_rows"
    :page="table_page"
    :hide-default-footer=true
    :loading="table_loading"
    class="elevation-2"
>
</v-data-table>
```

I was hoping that appending the [display-2](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/typography) class will do the trick for me, but it seems it doesn't have any effect:

```
<v-data-table
    dense
    :headers="table_headers"
    :items="table_data"
    :items-per-page="table_rows"
    :page="table_page"
    :hide-default-footer=true
    :loading="table_loading"
    class="elevation-2 display-2"
>
</v-data-table>
```

I also tried the following, but it simply renders a bunch of empty `row` elements. This is not shocking, as I suppose vuetify now expects that I will provide a complete template for each of the rows?

```
<v-data-table
    dense
    :headers="table_headers"
    :items="table_data"
    :items-per-page="table_rows"
    :page="table_page"
    :hide-default-footer=true
    :loading="table_loading"
    class="elevation-2"
>
    <template v-slot:item="props">
        <tr class="display-2"></tr>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

In my last attempt my code rendered more `td` elements per row than I expected, also all the columns were empty:

```
<v-data-table
    dense
    :headers="table_headers"
    :items="table_data"
    :items-per-page="table_rows"
    :page="table_page"
    :hide-default-footer=true
    :loading="table_loading"
    class="elevation-2"
>
    <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="row in items">
            <td v-for="col in row"
                class="display-2">
                {{ col }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

What am I doing wrong, is there a simpler way?

BTW: I'm not a JavaScript dev.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many columns, you can use a slot for each and wrap them in a div with a custom class like below:

```
<template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
   <div class="customStyle">{{ item.name }}</div>
</template>
```

edit: 
In your case when you get columns dynamically, you can use body slot as you already tried but then you will have a custom styling for the whole table body. Give it a try as below, it is untested.

```
<template v-slot:body="{ items }">
  <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" class="customClass">
    <td v-for="col in cols">
      {{ item.col }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

'cols' should be an array of column names as string that you are fetching dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, but my table columns are dynamic, thus I cannot predict which ones or how many of them gonna be presented on the page.

Answer (score 1):

@Cristian D.'s answer is the most concise, but it should be "cellClass" instead of "Class" for vuetify v2.

See https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props-headers

For instance

```
headers: [{text: 'Name', value:'name', cellClass: "text-caption"}]
```

Comment: You should probably add the code to your answer, otherwise it might be seen as a comment or a partial answer and get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's important you don't use the style 'scoped'.

```
    <style>
        .my_class td{
            font-size: small!important;
            height: 0!important;
            padding: 1px!important;
        }
    </style>
```

The v-data-table must be the specified class 'my-class'

```
    <v-data-table class="my-class" :items="my_output"  >
    </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use the style scoped.

```css
#my_custom_table tr td {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<v-data-table
    id="my_custom_table"
    dense
    :headers="table_headers"
    :items="table_data"
    :items-per-page="table_rows"
    :page="table_page"
    :hide-default-footer=true
    :loading="table_loading"
    class="elevation-2"
>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It works for me  don't use the style scoped.

```
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th{
     font-size: 16px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to apply any style in particular through "style".
When you are working with tables, you should declare your headers in data() like this:

```
data() { headers: [{ text: "Title of your row", sortable: true, class: "*"}]
```

Here in the * you can replace it with any font size Vuetify offers you. You can see all of these in here:

https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/typography/

So if you want the font to be good for an h3, you should replace the * above with:

```
class: "display-2"
```

Hope this helps. Also, if you want to have a specific color, you can use the class "primary--text" and it will grab the "primary" value from your actual vuetify theme. See more of this in here:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/